# Object too dark after solidify from an SVG

Tags: svg

**I've:**

1. Created a voronoi pattern as an SVG
2. Imported SVG to Blender.
3. Turned SVG into a Mesh.
4. Used "Solidify" to "extrude" the mesh.

I now have a 3D object - I do only hard surface modelling for 3D printing.

**The issue:**
The object is very dark (no matter what Viewport shading I use) and I can see vertices, edges & faces ONLY in wireframe mode (see image below).

**Question:** how can I light my object to appear as other "native" Blender objects?

[image: Object is too dark]

Thanks,
Roy

Comment: I guess when you imported it, it has a created a material with the color your svg had. Go in the Material panel and delete this material

Comment: Thanks! that did the trick :)

Answer (score 0):

When you imported your svg object, it automatically created a material with the color of your svg. Go in the *Properties* panel > *Material* panel and delete this material.